# Add version to shared library name in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, shared-libraries

I'm amble to easily create a shared library in eclipse, setting project's proprerties:

```
C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Build Artifact
    Artifact Type: Shared Library
    Artifact Name: ${ProjName}
    Artifact Extensione: so
    Output Prefix: lib
```

So when I compile, output is:

```
lib<libraryName>.so
```

Question is: **how can I automatically add version number?** Like:

```
lib<libraryName>.so.1.0
```

I've no idea about.

I'm using SVN for version control.

Comment: Do you want to name your library with a number at the end like your example (feel free, but that's normally only done on Windows which lack soversions), or add a soversion (`lib<libraryName>.so.1.0`)?

Comment: Note, that subversion has nothing to do with this. Soversion indicates version of the ABI and often does not match releases, not to mention version control revisions.

Comment: That was to say, it can't be filled "automatically". You have to fill it in the projects settings somewhere (but I use CMake for building, so I don't know where the setting is in Eclipse).